# How to connect google fit on ios react native

Tags: ios, react-native, google-fit

currently I only see the google fit support library on android, is there any library that supports connect google fit on react native ios?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by the Google Fit SDK. Feel free filling a feature request through [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) so engineers can track them. Product team will review the requests and take them under consideration for future engineering work.